# Angular 4 - Template URLs Changing from https to http?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular2-template

I have a template in my Angular 4 app that pulls images from an https:// URL, and works fine when the app is hosted locally via 'ng serve':

```
<div class="poster_div" *ngIf="movie_details['poster_path']">
  <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185{{movie_details['poster_path']}}" />
</div>
```

However-- now that I've deployed the site ( and am serving it with Apache HTTP), these images are being pulled from http instead (causing the dreaded 'mixed content' error in the browser).  Is there a setting in 'ng build' that causes this? Or is is some wacky side effect with Apache?

'Inspect Element' from local:

```
<img _ngcontent-c1="" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/ApYhuwBWzl29Oxe9JJsgL7qILbD.jpg">
```

'Inspect Element' from remote site:

```
<img _ngcontent-c1="" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/ApYhuwBWzl29Oxe9JJsgL7qILbD.jpg">
```

Comment: this sounds like a CORS problem have you double checked that your server is configured correctly for that?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" is in the response headers when I visit the site...

Comment: Doesn't CORS just affect JavaScript requests?

Comment: You're probably right - any time I see "mixed content" I just assume it's CORS :)

Comment: could you please share your deployment script or environment to allow others to help you. This is probably related with CORS as the other suggested, but I would like to give you a full answer ;)

Comment: If you discover this is related with CORS + Apache, then you should try this https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html. Hope it helps :)

Comment: The error you're getting is CORS (which affects any resource, not just JS requests), but that doesnt sound like the root of the problem If I understand your question correctly. If the images are linked with https locally and then http on the server, then the issue is (as you suggested) in the build or apache. Can you view the files on the server to see if they are correct there? (if not, try running your build script locally and see what it generates)

Comment: I'm just using whatever the defaults are for 'ng build --prod'.  I found the <img> tag in 'main.bundle.js', and it looks a-ok:
[ can't post the code because it's being interpreted as a link-- but the 'src' attribute of the 'img' tag starts with 'https://'... ]

Comment: Another note: I read over the 'ng build' documentation, and I don't see any configuration options that would affect HTML tags in template files...I mean, the code gets minified and uglified with a prod build, but surely that wouldn't have an effect as far as changing 'https' to 'http' in a template file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the protocol from your image URL, so you have a relative URL. This will then use the correct protocol that the visitor is using when visiting the site.

```
<div class="poster_div" *ngIf="movie_details['poster_path']">
  <img src="//image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185{{movie_details['poster_path']}}" />
</div>
```

Comment: So simple, and I feel so dumb.  Thank you , J J B!